# How convert .svg to .ttf without Browser tools

Tags: fonts, svg, truetype

I want to convert .svg to .ttf used command line toos.

I searched way for convert.
Browser tool found but CLI tool was not found.

Please tell me if you know

Comment: If by svg you mean an svg font, then the reverse of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087903/command-line-tool-for-converting-ttf-otf-fonts-to-svg should work fine (the fontforge variant).

Comment: Thank you. Ican convert svg this way.