# how to convert truetypefont file to svg in python

Tags: python, svg, truetype

I need to convert some ttf file to svg file
I know I can use fontforge by script,but I wish I can do this in python
I assume there is some protocols of the ttf file so I can parser it from binary to human readable svg,but I couldn't find the protocol any where(I use bing searched)
Is there is some way I can do this?The protocol or a already made python lib would be ok

Comment: did u find the solution for this using pure python?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question for the command-line:
[Command-line tool for converting TTF/OTF fonts to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087903/command-line-tool-for-converting-ttf-otf-fonts-to-svg)
You could simply call it in a subprocess.

Comment: As I said,I know I can use fontforge,I wish to find a pure python way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Since this can be done with FontForge, you can simply use the `fontforge` library in Python.
It can be installed using this command in Linux: (idk how to install it on other OSes)

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-fontforge
```

Then, in pure Python:

```py
import fontforge

def ttf2svg(i,o):
    font = fontforge.open(i)
    font.generate(o)
    font.close()
```

After this, just call the function like this:

```
ttf2svg([input filename], [output_filename])
```